# How can I find the DC gain or the constant of a given Bode diagram with no y-axis given (H(s)=K(s(s+1))/((10s+1)(s+10)(s+100)))?

Tags: power-electronics, transfer-function, math, diagram

[image]

The answer is K= 1000 but i dont get why. Calculating gives me G(0)=0.001

Comment: also it shows 0dB above middle plateau or livello , so K is not the DC gain but overall gain  near=1 or 0 dB at omega =30 , the log midpoint, or near 5 Hz.  VK shows the correct results.

Comment: The DC gain is zero by simple inspection of the graph. End of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When s>>1, H(s) is aproximative to K/10s:

\$ H(s)=\frac{Ks(s+1)}{(10s+1)(s+10)(s+100)} = \frac{K}{10} \frac{s(s+1)}{(s+0.1)(s+10)(s+100)} = (limit ~ s>>1) ~ \frac{K}{10} \frac{1}{s} \$

At s=100, the diagtam gives asymptotic value H(s)=0dB=1=K/(10*100), thus, K=1000

** Addendum **

Assume a different problem, same graph but 0 dB at s=0.1

We can use two different methods:

a) if 0 dB at s=0.1, following the graph, 20 dB at s=100. Now, apply same formula than in previous: H(100)=20dB=10=K/(10*100) so K=10000

b) if s<<1 H(s)=Ks/1000 in approximation. At s=0.1 we have H(0.1)=0dB=1=K 0.1 / 1000, thus K=10000

Comment: Can you explain me a general method to find this constant, i'm getting mad!

Comment: The only value you know, in the graph, is value from 10 to 100 (0 dB). Thus, you must calculate H(s) for some know value and made the result equal to this value.

Comment: So first you study K* limit s->infinite  H(s)= K/10s then you calculate the value in s=100 right?

Comment: Yes, is as yoy say

Comment: Note the author of the problem is doing bad things, not all terms in the denominator are in the form (s+a)

Comment: thank a lot you save my day for tomorrow exam!

Comment: Now, second problem: same graph, but 0dB at s=1

Comment: if 0db is at s=1 then K=10?

Comment: Ooops, no, smaller K moves graph down, we have moved it "up" in the se ond example. Hints: evaluate in the graph the value at s=100 and apply same formulad than in previous; or evaluate aproximation when s<<1 and apply same method at s=0.1

Comment: s<<1 So K*lim s-> -Infinite H(s)= K/10s this time is "<<" so it means i have to choose 0.1 value then K this time is equal to 1?

Comment: s>>1 provides the expression for the line at the right of the graph, the related formula can only be used for points in this line, in your example, s=100 and up.

Comment: Then i dont understand, can you give me the solution? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Answer updated with second example

Answer (score 1):

Your transfer function is given by the following expression:

\$H(s)=k\frac{s(1+s)}{(1+10s)(s+10)(s+100)}\$

As this equation is not fitting a low-entropy format, you can advantageously rewrite it as

\$H(s)=\frac{k}{1000}\frac{s(1+s)}{(1+10s)(\frac{s}{10}+1)(\frac{s}{100}+1)}\$

There is a zero at the origin, hence no gain in dc. From the given graph, it seems that the magnitude flattens out at 0 dB if I understand the comment "livello 0 dB" correctly. It means that in the above expression, the leading term must equal 1 thus asking for a value of \$k\$ equal to 1000 as correctly pointed out by Pasaba Por Aqui. The below Mathcad graph confirms this number.

[image]

Comment: what if level 0 db was at s=0.1?

Comment: To highlight the first gain plateau (-20 dB), you must resort to an inverted pole, e.g. factor \$10\tau s\$ in the denominator and simplify by \$s\tau\$ in the numerator, the leading term becomes \$\frac{G_0}{1000.10}\$ which is 0.1 or -20 dB.